# how to generate report between two date which are linked to cells that are linked to ranges of cells in multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba, countif

Im trying to create a "Report Generator" in excel using command button(VBA) to generate the report after entering the range of date i want in two cell,
sheet1 has at B2 and D2, which only contains dates (FROM & TO), which are from 1/1/2019 to 31/12/2019

i tried linking the two dates, to other 12 sheets (each month)
in each sheet, each day contains 50 rows and 40 columns
Starting with the date of the day in cell B2,B52,B102,B152...ETC.

im successful in doing the following (easy part)
using command button(VBA) in the months' sheet to only show the 50 rows of the day i want, i was able to hide unneeded rows after choosing date in cell A1 (with date drop down list) and clicking on command button next to it in cell A2, using number of dates (43466 = 1/1/2019, 43467 = 2/1/2019...etc.)
sample of VBA code below (it goes over 1000 lines, with each sheet containing 100 or so lines, with command button to "refresh" and show only the day i want)

im unsuccessful in doing the following (hard part)
trying different formulas and vba to link the two dates in sheet1 (B2 and D2) to specific cell in specific sheet to use as FROM & TO in generating report, and linking the cell to a range below it using OFFSET, and use COUNTIF to count the specific data in each column

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim TriggerCell As Range
    Set TriggerCell = Range("C1")

    If TriggerCell.Value = "Show Entire Month" Then
        Rows("2:1644").Hidden = False
    ElseIf TriggerCell.Value = 43466 Then
        Rows("2:1644").Hidden = True
        Rows("2:54").Hidden = False
    ElseIf TriggerCell.Value = 43467 Then
        Rows("2:1644").Hidden = True
        Rows("55:107").Hidden = False
    End If

End Sub
```

i expect the output in cells under the main sheet (sheet1)
to calculate the ranges between the specified dates and count the specific data which were entered and produce it, then generate charts based on those results, and creating a fully automatic report generator if possible

[image]

Comment: Some print screens of data or at least a sample would help. Show how the data is and the output that you want.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz Added a Picture, explaining some of the sheets and what i want to do, all outputs i need are going to be in numbers which i'm going to link to charts.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first/quick approach.

Read this information first as there are some disadvantages depending on how much data you're dealing with: http://www.mcgimpsey.com/excel/threedsumif.html

You could use the last suggestion given in the link and create the 3D formula using countifs

Steps I made to create the example:

1- Add sheets names in G3:G5

2- Added formula to cell D3:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT(""&G3:G5&"!$C:$C");">="&$B$3;INDIRECT(""&G3:G5&"!$C:$C");"<="&$C$3;INDIRECT(""&G3:G5&"!$D:$D");D$2))
```

[image]

This was based on this set up in each sheet:

[image]

The key here is to use the countifs function that allows you to filter dates using >= or <= and include other criteria (inclusive - and).

Note: As stated in several forums, Sumproduct is volatile and it tends to slow the workbooks if it is used in ranges that include lots of cells.

I'd need to know how you're updating the report's data and with how much data you're dealing with to come up with other approaches.

If this helps, remember to mark the answer so it can help others too